# displaying a string twice?

Tags: php, mysql

i created a script that connects to my database called mysqlconnecter:

```
    <?php

define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "pass");
define("DB_DATABASE", "adventure_of_dragons");
define("DB_SERVER", "127.0.0.1");

$db_handle = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

$db_found = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $db_handle);

if ($db_found || true) {

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    $id = $row['member_id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $rank = $row['rank'];


}

mysql_close($db_handle);

} else {
echo "Database NOT Found " . $db_handle;
}

?>
```

And then I created another script that includes mysqlconnecter.php and posts the data inside the database:

```
<?php

include  "mysqlconnecter.php";
    echo 'ID = ' . $id . '<br>';
    echo 'RANK = ' . $rank . '<br>';
    echo 'USERNAME = ' . $username . '<br>';
    echo 'PASSWORD = ' . $password . '<br><br>';
    // two <br>'s, so we get an empty line between users

    ?>
```

but the output displays the data inside the database twice:

```
ID = 4
RANK = 100
USERNAME = user
PASSWORD = password

ID = 4
RANK = 100
USERNAME = user
PASSWORD = password
```

I only want it displaying the text once,
What do I do?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Is that your whole code, don't you have another loop somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is slightly the wrong way round.

This is because your loop is finished `then` you are echoing the data so it will always be the last row.

You need to echo whilst in the loop or create an array then loop the array later.

```
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

    $id = $row['member_id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $rank = $row['rank'];
 //this will echo for EVERY row the loop iterates.
    echo 'ID = ' . $id . '<br>';
    echo 'RANK = ' . $rank . '<br>';
    echo 'USERNAME = ' . $username . '<br>';
    echo 'PASSWORD = ' . $password . '<br><br>';

  }
```

For your double output i suspect you have included the file twice. But thats guessing as i don't see all of your code.

Comment: And how would I do that? @Dave

Comment: @FireRaven101 I just gave you the code... echo the data inside your while loop not outside. Then you will get each row once only.

Comment: Also listen to @koala_dev with his MYSQL_* advice. It it s highly recommend you make the switch :)

Comment: how does this explain the odd behavior that there is actually two printouts where it shouldn't?

Comment: But i am going to need to output the username on different pages though, so what would i do? @Dave

Comment: @jocke See last line in my answer.. his code provided does not give us enough info.

Comment: @FireRaven101 so you are echo'n that data in a second place? that would explain why you are seeing two outputs for the same user...

Comment: @FireRaven101 one option is make a function to hold the members and then you can echo it when ever you wish then by calling the function. But that is a different problem which would be best as a second question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the display code outside your mysqlconnecter.php file, you could do this in your loop:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row['member_id'];
        'username' => $row['username'];
        'password' => $row['password'];
        'rank' => $row['rank'];
}
```

And then in your script:

```
include  "mysqlconnecter.php";
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    echo 'ID = ' . $value['id'] . '<br>';
    // etc
}
```

For your "double print" problem, I would try to put a  `var_dump($data);` right after your `while()` in mysqlconnecter.php, to see what happens exactly.

If the var_dump display correctly reflects the expected result of your query, the problem is elsewhere, possibly that you include mysqlconnecter.php twice, as Dave suggested. To be sure it's included only once throughout your whole code, simply replace `include()` with `include_once()`.

Comment: So that means he had double included as i first thought. Include_once although fixes it, still suggests the code he has needs re-doing correctly.

Comment: You're right but since the OP didn't seem to bother about having included it twice or had no idea on earth where to look for and seeing that his code is so bad in so many ways, I just chose to give him what he was waiting for, so that he can move forward. He has time to learn the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have any mistake? is that all code you show us?
Because logically your script will print once and will print the last data from your members table
I have try it